# Why is Helena from Orphan Black blonde?

Tags: orphan-black

Helena is one of the Leda clones in Orphan Black. However, unlike the other Leda clones, who have dark hair, Helena's hair is very light. Why is this?

Comment: Probably she dyes it.

Comment: Women and their hair color, are things men need not think about, as it makes no sense ;) Katja (the German clone) was a red head..

Comment: @FuxieDK, Katja was clearly dyed though. Hair colour should have been consistent among the clones though.

Comment: @ NoahM, which is why I wrote men need not think of women and their hair color.. Most of them color it.

Answer (score 5):

Helena bleaches her hair. It's pretty obvious that her roots are much darker.

Why she bleaches it is an entirely different question. Early on, she had a very strong angel fetish. Angels are frequently depicted with a glowing radiance around their heads (a halo), so she may have been trying to replicate that effect. In the final season, we see the first time it is done...

> ...against her will as part of a punishment when she was a child...

...but we still don't know why she *kept* doing it.

> It may be part of her self-flagellation, but there's no solid, on-screen statement to that effect.

Out-of-universe, they do it so we can tell which clone is which at a glance.

[image: Helena's Roots]

FYI, Krystal bleaches and has dark roots, too:

[image: Krystal's Roots]

Comment: Then why are her roots consistently dark? If she dyed her hair, she'd sometimes have light roots

Comment: @Noah Because she dies it, then her hair grows back in its natural (darker) color.  Hence dark roots.  Unless she died it in the last week, her roots will basically always be dark.

Comment: @Noah: Out of universe, it's a wig. The series doesn't have any need to keep precise track of time, so maintaining multiple wigs for differing bleach ages is a waste of money.

Comment: @DaveJohnson, one would assume that she would have different amounts of root colour, which IIRC is not the case.

Comment: @T.J.L., I realise it's a wig, I would think that they could produce a couple of different colourations of wigs without breaking the budget.

Comment: @Noah Helena's hair treatment schedule is _completely_ irrelevant to the _plot_. There's no _good_ reason to _care_. He hair is different for clone identification purposes, that's it. Wether or not they could afford it has no bearing on whether or not it's a waste of money. If it's not a plot point, it's a waste of money.

Comment: @T.J.L., I personally think the out-of-universe rationale works better. Also, I don't see how bleaching her hair is really in character, particularly with her upbringing with a zealot like Tomas.

Comment: @T.J.L. actually, it's not _completely_ irrelevant, as shown in S5E09 (see my answer), although I agree we didn't know that over a year ago.

Comment: @SQB The *schedule* is completely irrelevant to the plot, which is the only plays I used the the word "irrelevant". The reason is still not clearly explained. We now know *when* her hair was bleached the first time and *why*, but we *still* don't know why she *keeps* it that way.

Answer (score 3):

In episode S5E09, "One Fettered Slave", Helena has flashbacks to her youth in the convent, in which we see a young Helena getting punished by a nun by having her hair (violently) bleached.

In other flashbacks as well as in early episodes, we see she practises self-punishment, so she may have kept her hair bleached as a form of that.